# MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, modulenotfounderror

**Tried many times always showed below, even the folder exists** :

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/vincent/Desktop/Seneca Course/Web Programming WEB 700/Assignment/Assignment 2 Code/collegeData.js'

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

{
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

requireStack: []

}

Comment: Remove the filename extension from the path.

Comment: Try naming your folders with no space. Seneca Course => Seneca_Course, Web Programming WEB 700 => Web_Programming_WEB_700... etc. .Don't forget to fix your imports as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.